# Retrofit2+RxJava Return null to Model class in OnNext()

Tags: java, android, retrofit2

I'm sending a simple get method to my server and get the result using RxJava and Retrofit. The thing that I did is:

Interface

```
public interface Posts {

    @GET("/typicode/demo/{path}")
    Observable<List<Beans>> getPosts(@Path("path") String path);
}
```

RetrofitInstance

```
public static Retrofit getInstance() {
        if (retrofit == null) {
            HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
            interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
            OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder().addInterceptor(interceptor).build();
            retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.createWithScheduler(Schedulers.io()))
                    .client(client)
                    .build();
        }
        return retrofit;
    }
```

MainActivity

```
Observer<List<Beans>> observer = new Observer<List<Beans>>() {
            @Override
            public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onNext(List<Beans> value) {
                Log.d("Saket", value.toString());
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Throwable e) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onComplete() {

            }
        };
        Posts client = RetrofitClientInstance.getInstance().create(Posts.class);
        client.getPosts("posts").observeOn(Schedulers.newThread()).subscribeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()).subscribe(observer);
```

I am getting correct output using `HTTPLoggingInterceptor`.

Comment: Why do you observe on a `newThread` and subscribe on a `mainThread`? And what is the exact question?

Comment: @MDikkii I am trying to do network operation in a background thread and want to post result in mainThread (UI Thread). But in onNext callback, I am getting my List as null.

Comment: Post your json response. Are you getting any exception?

Comment: Then you should observe on `mainThread` and do task (subscribe on) `newThread` (or io).

Comment: com.lite.myapplication D/OkHttp:     "id": 1,
com.lite.myapplication D/OkHttp:     "title": "Post 1"
com.lite.myapplication D/OkHttp:   },
com.lite.myapplication D/OkHttp:   {
com.lite.myapplication D/OkHttp:     "id": 2,
com.lite.myapplication D/OkHttp:     "title": "Post 2"
com.lite.myapplication D/OkHttp:   },
com.lite.myapplication D/OkHttp:   {
com.lite.myapplication D/OkHttp:     "id": 3,
com.lite.myapplication D/OkHttp:     "title": "Post 3"
com.lite.myapplication D/OkHttp:   }

No exceptions. When I try to print using in OnNext Call back all JSON responses are null.

Answer (score 2):

You can use subscribeWith like this

also change subscribe on to --> Schedulers.newThread() or Schedulers.io()
right now you are making network call on UI thread

```
 client.getPosts("posts")
                    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread()) // change
                    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()) // change
                    .subscribeWith(new Observer<Response<Observable<List<Beans>>>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onNext(Response<Observable<List<Beans>>> response) {

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onError(Throwable e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();


                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onComplete() {


                        }
                    });
```

Answer (score 0):

It works when I use Single Observable and DisposableSingleObserver as an observer.